# Awk input and output file delimiter

Tags: bash, shell, awk, solaris

I try to parse a column delimited password file using awk and put hostname in the beginning and add some fields. I need a comma separated output. So what I try is:

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F':'  MYHOST=$(hostname)  'BEGIN{OFS=",";} {print MYHOST, $1, $3, $4, $5;}'  /etc/passwd
```

But this command didn't produce output I wanted. This is a Solaris box, regular awk didn't work so I try with  /usr/xpg4/bin/awk

Comment: On solaris, you should always prefer /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk over /usr/bin/awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may help you:

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F':'  -v MYHOST="$(hostname)"  'BEGIN{OFS=","} {print MYHOST, $1, $3, $4, $5;}'  /etc/passwd
```

Comment: @JavaRed Small variation: `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F:  -vMYHOST="$(hostname)" -vOFS, '{print MYHOST,$1,$3,$4,$5}'  /etc/passwd`